# How to download a file using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i want to download a file from local when i click link button it should download a file from specific path. In my case it throws

> 'C:/Search/SVGS/Documents/img.txt' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected.

```
protected void lnkbtndoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkbtndoc = new LinkButton();
    var SearchDoc = Session["Filepath"];
    string file = SearchDoc.ToString();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + file + "\"");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(file));
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below code to download the file on link button click

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Download"
            OnClick="btnDownload_OnClick" />
protected void btnDownload_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "~/Downloads/msizap.exe";
        if (filename != "")
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath(filename);
            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it throws'C:/Search/SVGS/Documents/img.txt' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected. in string path = Server.MapPath(filename);

Comment: if you already know your folder is: D:\PRAVIN\File then you do not need to use Server.MapPath, this last one is needed if you only have a relative virtual path like ~/folder/Pravin and you want to know the real path in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Check Any of these .

[StreamReader Server.MapPath - Physical path given, virtual path expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277062/streamreader-server-mappath-physical-path-given-virtual-path-expected)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/624307/Server-MapPath-Physical-path-given-virtual-path-ex

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/508243/aplusphysicalpluspath-cplusbutplusaplusvirtualplu

Answer (score 0):

In your code just change this line :

```
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(file));
```

to

```
Response.TransmitFile(file);
```

This because of you are sending the physical path not the virtual path as `Server.MapPath` expects. Also read this [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath) it will help you to understand how to deal with `Server.MapPath` method