# download excel file from server to local machine in asp.net using web API and javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, epplus

this is my code:
Html:

```
 <a class="castrol_button " data-bind="click: createExcelFile">download excel file</a>
```

In js part of my code I have this

```
   createExcelFile = function (data, event) {
   //call an API
 }
```

in my controller I Have this code :

```
   [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreatePaymentExcelFile(long Customerid)
      {
        try
        {
        // get data from DB to list which name is lst
        // using epplus dll for creating Excel file
     var file =new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DesktopModules/Castrolo2c/Resource/PaymentList.xlsx");

        using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PaymentList");
            if (worksheet != null)
            {
                int row = 2;
                foreach( var i in res )
                {

                    worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = i.typename;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = i.pNO;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = i.Date;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = i.cashdate;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = i.Money;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = i.bedehkari;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = i.bestankari;
                    row++;
                }
                worksheet.Column(1).Width = 16;
                xlPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "patments";

                xlPackage.Workbook.Properties.Company = "Castrol";

                xlPackage.Save();

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "ERR"));
        } }
```

every thing is fine and my excel file has been created in the  folder in my server. but I want to copy the file to client machine. how can I do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Download file to client browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897458/asp-net-download-file-to-client-browser)

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106904/how-to-download-a-file-using-asp-net

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477398/asp-net-file-download-from-server

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650/how-to-implement-a-file-download-in-asp-net

Comment: I find all that by searching the Internet with the terms `asp.net download file`. I think you should try to get those skills as well.

Comment: @ThomasWeller thanks a lot. I 've already checked this links my problem actually was in js part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job

JS should be like:

```
createExcelFile = function (data, event) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    window.location.href = '...'; //The Api Address
}
```

and the Api:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetExcel()
    {
        using (var p = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("My WorkSheet");
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "A1";

            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(p.GetAsByteArray());

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(stream)
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "myworkbook.xlsx"
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You return http code so instead of this you should return

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("", "");
        Response.Charset = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename="MyFile.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        Response.BinaryWrite(xlPackage.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
```